# How to pull back my paper from conference?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, self-plagiarism

My first year undergraduate teammate submitted our paper to two conferences yesterday. I am afraid that this can lead to self plagiarism. Help me. How do I withdraw our paper? What should I say to conference organizers? This is a deeply concerning problem. Please help.

Comment: What exactly did you do and what do you want to achieve? What is 'double plagiarism'? The question is unclear to me.

Comment: I edited it back. Sorry for bad post previously.

Comment: "double submission" is probably what OP means. Write to the conference chairs you want to retract, immediately, explain the mistake and people should understand that undergraduates make mistakes out of inexperience.

Comment: I just want to emphasize that you should act very quickly. The papers are typically assigned to reviewers within the first 3 to 7 days. Withdrawing the paper when it has not been assigned yet can avoid potential damage for your reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which conference you have submitted. There are several interfaces (the most popular one being [easychair](http://easychair.org/)), and each of them has an option to withdraw paper before notification of acceptance (or rejection).

Just log into the website and click withdraw paper button.

Comment: Hmm. I currently have submissions in three conferences with EasyChair, and none of them has the "Withdraw" button. Maybe it's an option that the conference chairs can switch on and off.

Comment: Or maybe the button is only available in the timeframe between the submission and the moment when the conference is closed for submissions. From then on, you would have to contact the chairs.